# Is Redis used to store auto-incrementing IDs for databases

Tags: mongodb, redis

I am planning on using Redis to generate and store autoincrementing IDs that I will use as primary key fields in MongoDB.

Is this a good idea given the resiliency and durability of Redis.  I am worried that if Redis goes down, I might have to deal with duplicate key issues in MongoDB.

I'm planning on implementing Redis using the Append Only File option, and performing an fsync every time a new command is appended to the AOF.  It will be slower but more durable.

I am planning on sharding MongoDB in the future and would like to have the IDs be sequential instead of of using Mongo's internal time based IDs.

Comment: Why do you want to use Redis for this? Why not just use MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Might work, but if that is your only use for redis, seems like a bunch of complexity for something that is already available right in mongodb:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Actually, planning on using Redis for a whole lot more in my application.  Regarding creating the auto-increment in Mongo, it won't scale when you have multiple Mongo shards.  (each shard then creates its own IDs which collide).  That's the sole reason why I want to do this in Redis

Comment: @Arcane A sharded cluster should not be making a id per shard, what makes you think that?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking that the IDs had to be unique if I was going to use ranges for partitioning the app.  (i.e. All users with IDs 1 through 1000) are on server A, 1001 to 2000 are on server B, etc.  Please correct me if I am wrong, and there is a better way I should be thinking about this.

Comment: Also, on the link provided above, there is a warning as follows:

Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, or any field, because it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents. Typically the default value ObjectId is more ideal for the _id.

Maybe you could elaborate as why this warning is given, perhaps I am misunderstanding the reason.

Comment: @Arcane Yes, that ranging should be occuring on a colleciton level, since you would use a separate collection as a counter that counter will be globally unque to the cluster. As for the warning, that is why MongoDB does not implement a incrementing ID, it is the same problem as in SQL techs, to be honest if you can get away from it I would not go for one, it is slow and each insert must atomically take a value from the counters collection on eahc insert

Comment: @Arcane Also doing that range will cause hot spots and in turn problems in sharding, what you want is a random yet even distribution of your data so that all of the cluster is being utilised for writes and reads, else you might as well just be using a single server

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research and watching the training videos on 10gen, I see that the approach to use sequential IDs is flawed, so I will not use Redis in this fashion.